# Is char *envp[] as a third argument to main() portable

Tags: c, environment-variables, program-entry-point, portability, function-signature

In order to get an environment variable in a `C` program, one could use the following:

- `getenv()`
- `extern char **environ;`

But other than the above mentioned, is using `char *envp[]` as a third argument to `main()` to get the environment variables considered part of the standard?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    while(*envp)
        printf("%s\n",*envp++);
}
```

Is `char *envp[]` portable?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The function `getenv` is the only one specified by the C standard. The function [`putenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html), and the extern [`environ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/environ.html) are POSIX-specific.

#### EDIT

The `main` parameter `envp` is not specified by POSIX but is widely supported.

> An alternative method of accessing the environment list is to declare
>   a third argument to the main() function:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
> ```
>
> This argument can then be treated in the same way as environ, with the
>   difference that its scope is local to main(). Although this feature is
>   widely implemented on UNIX systems, its use should be avoided since,
>   in addition to the scope limitation, **it is not specified in SUSv3**.

Comment: Note that the C standard recognizes this as a common alternative — even C89 mentioned it in Annex G (Portability Issues); it is in Annex J (Portability Issues) in both C99 and C11.

Comment: It does not work with (at least) z/OS 2.4 and xlc/c99/c89 on the IBM Mainframe. There is a [POSIX solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649273/where-is-the-definition-of-extern-char-environ).

Answer (score 24):

It isn't portable. `*envp[]` is a traditional UNIX thing, and not all modern UNIX systems implement it.

Also as a side note you could access envp by doing a pointer traversal over `*argv[]`, overflowing it...but i don't think that can be considered *safe* programming. If you take a look at the process memory map you will see that `envp[]` is just above `argv[]`.

Comment: And you can go past the environment too and examine `auxv`... ;-)

Comment: What is usually stored in auxv, because i was just wondering the other days why where the fields after envp constant(between runs)?

Comment: Look in `elf.h` for the macros beginning with `AT_`. Some of the more interesting things are `AT_SECURE`, `AT_RANDOM`, `AT_EXECFN`, `AT_HWCAP`, and the uid/gid ones. Otherwise they're mostly of interest to the dynamic linker and libc init code. The format of `auxv` is pairs of system-word-size integers, the first of which is one of the `AT_` constants (a tag) and the second of which is the value associated with that tag (possibly a pointer, depending on the tag).

Comment: What about using a pointer to find the end of argv, and going one step further? `char **find = argv, **envp; while(*find) find++; envp = find + 1;` Probably undefined behavior since an OS isn't guaranteed to put environment stuff after argv's last arg...

Comment: More traditional/idiomatic and concise version of the last comment's way: `char **envp = argv; while(*envp++);`

Answer (score 19):

The Standard describes two formats for `main` (see 5.1.2.2.1 in the [C99 Standard (pdf)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf))

a) `int main(void)`

and

b) `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent

and it allows implementations to define other formats (which can allow a 3rd argument)

c)  or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: An implementation _may_ provide further formats for `main`, but these two are the only ones guaranteed to be present in any hosted implementation.

Answer (score 12):

The 3rd argument is valid in Microsoft C and GNU GCC:

[Visual Studio 2015: Arguments to main](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/k104fy6h.aspx)

[GNU C Programming Tutorial: Environment variables](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Environment-variables.html)