# where is the definition of extern char **environ?

Tags: c, linux

we can get the environment variable in C like this:

```
extern char **environ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count = 0;

    printf("\n");
    while(environ[count] != NULL)
   {
         printf("[%s] :: ", environ[count]);
         count++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

but where is the defination of environ? I can't find that in unistd.h. and how does it work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`environ` is defined as a global variable in the Glibc source file [`posix/environ.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/environ.c).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried declaring envp as parameter to main?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments

Answer (score 2):

man:

> This variable must be declared in the user program, but is declared in the header file unistd.h in case the header files came from libc4 or libc5, and in case they came from glibc and _GNU_SOURCE was defined.

Comment: why the different sources of header files make it inappropriate to define the variable in the unistd.h? can you make it clear?

Comment: @nzomkxia: You normally don't *define* variables (`char **environ = NULL;`) in header files, because header files are included in multiple translation units -- the multiple definitions would clash.  You can *declare* variables (`extern char **environ;`) in header files since multiple declarations are okay.

Comment: Is `extern char **environ;` really the standard way to get access to the variable from a program - nothing standard that we could `#include` to get the declaration?

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX systems, the identifier

```
extern char **environ;
```

does not have to be defined in any header.  As noted in [@triclosn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649315/4756299) to this question, "This variable must be declared in the user program ..."

Per [POSIX 7 **Environment Variables**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> The value of an environment variable is a string of characters. For a C-language program, an array of strings called the environment shall be made available when a process begins. The array is pointed to by the external variable environ, which is defined as:
>
> extern char **environ;

There is no POSIX requirement that the `environ` variable be declared in any header file, so on a POSIX-compliant system it's just available should you wish to declare it in your code.