# Meaning of char *arge[] as third parameter in main in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

What does  **char * arge[]** mean as third parameter in the main function in a C program ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[], char *arge[]) {
  int i;
  char **p;
  printf("pid = %d\n", getpid());
  printf("argc =  %d\n", argc);
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  printf("%s\n",argv[i] );
  p=arge;
  while (*p != NULL)
  printf("%s\n", *p++);
  execve("prog2", argv, arge);
  return 0;
}
```

"prog2" mentionned is this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[], char *arge[]) {
  printf("pid = %d\n", getpid());
  printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
  for(;;);
}
```

If you execute the code you will get all the environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of the third, environment variable argument to the C++ main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198797/whats-the-use-of-the-third-environment-variable-argument-to-the-c-main) (finders credits to @mort)

Comment: I added the code of my C program and what it returns

Comment: @Yunnosch the question then is what's the difference btw "arge[]" and "envp[]"

Answer (score 1):

The third argument is environment variables. It's answered in more depth here: [What's the use of the third, environment variable argument to the C++ main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198797/whats-the-use-of-the-third-environment-variable-argument-to-the-c-main)

Getting environment variables as a third argument to main seems to be specified in neither C nor POSIX though, so it's potentially not portable: [Is char *envp[] as a third argument to main() portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable)

Comment: While I learned something new (or better old) you should have flagged as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: The link which answers the question doesn't mention that it's am extension and not C or POSIX though, which I feel is important information.

Comment: I do agree that this info is important. However, the Q/A pair you found is better than you think. Comments and "other" answers do provide that information.

Comment: Or maybe the other proposed duplicate is more to your taste.

Comment: @mort you should right, this is an environment variables, the name given is just different. "argE" E like environment ..