# Can I setenv() using a envp?

Tags: c, env, setenv

I'm trying to setenv a new environement variable with setenv().

But I noticided that setenv() function set my new environement variable only if I use the environement "extern char **environ"

But I want to use the argument of the main() : "char **envp".

Here's the code I tried to do for setting in envp, but as you will see if you run that code, it won't be set in envp.

But if I use const char **environ it works.

Any ideas ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(int ac, char **av, char **envp)
{
  int   i;

  i = 0;
  setenv("NEW_ENV_VAR", "hello_world", 0);
  while (envp[i])
    printf("%s\n", envp[i++]);
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setenv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html)() is documented to not be allowed to change the optional `envp` argument to main.

If you need to iterate through all the environment variables, use the `extern char **environ` [variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable).

Comment: So, I have to recode setenv(), if I want to use envp, right ?

Comment: No. `envp` is a *local variable* in `main` and there is fundamentally no way for an external function to modify it. Use `extern char **environ;`. Or if you insist on using the `envp` variable, just write `envp = environ;` in `main` somewhere after the `setenv` call.