# main() function with wrong signature gets called

Tags: c, program-entry-point

The standard says:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters: int
>   main(void) { /* ... */ } or with two parameters (referred to here as
>   argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
>   function in which they are declared): int main(int argc, char *argv[])
>   { /* ... */ } or equivalent; 10) or in some other
>   implementation-defined manner.

If I write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct some_struct
{
    int i;
};

float main(struct some_struct s)
{
    printf("Why does this main get called?\n");
}
```

Actually, it gets called with any prototype, as I see, and there is no any runtime error.

Why isn't it forbidden? Are there no reasons for that? Also, how does it get called if the signature is wrong?

I've used `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Werror`or `-pedantic-errors` and you'll see it is not allowed.

Comment: Basically, if main() isn't typed, it defaults to int, if it is typed and not to an int -- it is an error.

Comment: Understood about compile flags, but how does it get called then? It just looks up for the function with name "main" and ignores any arguments?

Comment: The linker in C only looks at function names.  Including the arguments in the linkage is a C++ feature, required to support function overloads.  Well known as "name mangling".

Comment: I've got it. Thanks. Might write an answer so that I could accept it

Comment: argc and argv are pushed on the stack, main is called. All is well until you try to access the passed arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with standard conformance:

> 1  In this International Standard, ‘‘shall’’ is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, ‘‘shall not’’ is to be interpreted as a prohibition.

> 2  If a **‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement** that appears outside of a constraint or run time constraint is violated, the **behavior is undefined**. [...]

Look at the emphasis on the paragraph you quoted:

> [...]. It **shall** be defined with a return type of int and with [...]

In the case,

```
float main(struct some_struct s){...}
```

"shall" requirement is outside of constraint because standard clearly states that `main` return type shall be `int` either with no parameters

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

or with two parameters

```
 int main(int argc, char argv[]) { / ... */ }
```

This means that behavior of your program is *undefined*.

Comment: so, `main() { ... }` is undefined behaviour? I've seen it a lot

Comment: Allowed in C89. C99 and latter deprecated this signature.

Comment: We can also see main with a third parameter : environment variables. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10321474/14393739

Comment: This answer omits part of the text of the passage it quotes. Per C 2018 5.1.2.2.1, `main` may be defined “… or in some other implementation-defined manner.”

Comment: There might be some question in 5.1.2.2.1 1 about whether the sentence structure makes that “or” apply to just the parameters or to the return type as well. However, 5.1.2.2.3 1 makes it clear the standard makes provision for other return types: “If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`,… If the return type is not compatible with `int`,…”

Answer (score 2):

Your quote from the standard states that "some other implementation-defined manner".  It appears that gcc is quite liberal in what it allows as signatures for `main`; it seems to ignore the parameter that you're passing.  If you compile with `gcc -Wall`, you get warnings about main's prototype not being what it expects.

clang is less permissive about main's prototype.  It will accept the return type of `float` with a warning, but will error out on the struct argument.

C looks up functions by name only, so the linker doesn't care about the unusual return type and parameters.

Comment: That's odd of Clang. It feels the wrong way round. It should be a proper error to not have return type `int` (since there's no possible well-formed program that *also* has a `float main(...)`, since `main` must not be overloaded). However, implementations are free to support any kind of parameters for `main`, so it would be OK to say "your signature is ignored" or so and still be conforming.

Comment: “Implementation-defined” means the implementation **defines** it, that is, it states it in documentation. The fact that a program seems to “work” when compiled with GCC and executed does not mean the behavior is implementation-defined.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The C standard allows implementations to support return types other than `int` for `main`; C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 says `main` shall be defined “… or in some other implementation-defined manner.” However, I do not think that is what Clang is doing here. Rather, the requirements on the declaration of `main` are not constraints, and the C standard does not require a compiler to refuse to translate a program because of them. As C 2018 note 9 says, “… [An implementation] can also successfully translate an invalid program…”

Comment: @KerrekSB: Note also 5.1.2.2.3 1: “If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`,…” So the standard clearly makes provision for other return types for `main`.

Answer (score -1):

In C, if a function signature doesn’t specify any argument, it means that the function can be called with any number of parameters or without any parameters.

Hey checkout out this link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/