# Homework: Why is argv[2] defined?

Tags: c

I am getting a weird string for my argv[2], when I run this program without any inputs. Why isn't argv[2] undefined? `TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_T` <- That's what I get. I'm wondering if this has something to do with running it on a mac?

```
if(argv[2]) {
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lf", &argWind);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%20s",  str);
    sprintf(str2, "%lf", argWind);
    printf("String: %s, %lf", str, argWind);
    int len;
    len = strlen(str);
    str2[len] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(str, str2)){
        printf("\nError: you entered a non-numeric entry for wind speed\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly it's because you're on a mac. You should be able to test the len(sys.argv) to get the number of parameters passed, if you've not got a second parameter then it *should* be empty... perhaps it's reading the NULLPTR.

Comment: You must use `argc` to determine which elements of `argv[]` are valid. Anything in `argv[]` at index beyond `argc-1` is just stuff that happens to be there in memory. `argc` tells you how many elements in `argv[]` are valid. Note that the command name itself is in `argv[0]`. That's just how it works. It has nothing to do with the Mac.

Comment: This happens when I run it without arguments.

Comment: `argv` is simply defined as an array. It's your responsibility to check `argc` for the number of elements in that array and not exceed them.  `argv` is zero-based, so if `argc == 2` then the available elements of `argv` are 0 and 1. If you acess `argv[2]`, you're going past the end of the array and accessing random (uninitialized) memory and what you get as a result is undefined.

Comment: If `argc <= 1` and you are reading `argv[2]` you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks everyone! that answers all of my questions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen. In this case it looks like you're running past `argv` and into the third (less well known and certainly nonstandard) parameter of `main`, commonly called `envp`. [Relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable).

Answer (score 1):

argv[2] is the third parameter of the command line like this code, argc is the number of parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < argc; ++i)
  {
     printf("%d -> %s\n", i, argv[i]); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

See the process:

```
F:\so>tcc test.c

F:\so>test.exe a b c
0 -> test.exe
1 -> a
2 -> b
3 -> c
```

test.exe is the first, a is the second, b is third, c is the fourth.
If you run test.exe whitout other parameters, it will say argv[2] means b here is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

you'd better check "argc" firstly, then you can choose to use the valid "argv"