# How can I get the local shell variables in C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm currently working on my own replica of the history builtin.
I realize I need the HISTSIZE, HISTFILE and HISTFILESIZE variables to achieve the command options but I don't know how to get them. Is there a function similar to getenv or a variable like environ but with the local shell variables ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In your main declaration you can use `char **envp`, so it looks like : `int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` . Hope it helps

Comment: [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv)

Comment: I get no HIST variables with envp

Comment: If these are no environment variables, there is no way to get hold of them from a child process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a builtin is executed directly by the shell for 2 possible reasons:

- you avoid spawning a new processus (performance reason)
- it is the only way to have access to internal shell variables (your use case)

A shell could only provide access to its internal variables by two ways:

- either copy them to the environment because *by definition* the environment is the list of variables that are passed to child processes
- either provided an inter process communication mechanism (named pipe, private sockect, etc.) to allow its childs to ask them

AFAIK, no common shell implement either, but **you** can export the required shell variables to the environment:

```
export HIST
export HISTSIZE
export HISTFILESIZE
```

should be enough to later get them through `getenv`

Comment: So how does the echo command has an executable at /bin/echo ? It needs to access intern variables

Comment: @Fayeure It doesn't need to access internal variables. If you have `a=78` and you run the command `/bin/echo "it is $a"`, then _the shell_ replaces that with `/bin/echo "it is 78"` before the echo executable is told to do anything. The executable has no access to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The main declaration can have an extra argument, `char **envp`, which is an 2D array of char terminated by a NULL pointer. Here is an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
   int index = 0;
   while (envp[index])
       printf("%s\n", envp[index++];
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Using envp will provide you to get the environnement. To find shell variables, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-from-c-and-parse-its-output). I think that could help you.

Comment: envp only gives me the environment variables, I need HISTSIZE, HISTFILE and HISTFILESIZE which are shell variables. You can see those in the shell with the command "set"

Comment: `envp` as third parameter [isn't portable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

printf("SET = %s\n",getenv("SET"));

return 0;

}
```

To test Program, set the variable first and then execute :-

export SET=1

Answer (score 0):

As Steffan Hegny pointed out, there is no way to acces these variables if they are no environment variables. So `popen()`, what I thought could help, isn't a solution to your problem.

However if you need acces to those variables you can export their values to a real environment variable which can be accessed via `getenv(char*)`.

E.g.

```
export _HISTFILE=$HISTFILE && ./myProgram
```

or

```
_HISTFILE=$HISTFILE ./myProgram
```

with `myProgram` accessing the value like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  printf("History file: %s", getenv("_HISTFILE"));
}
```