# What does envp stand for?

Tags: c++, c, argv, abbreviation

I wonder what the abbreviation `envp` stands for, for example here:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
```

I also wonder what the `v` in `argv` initially stood for. Was the `v` for "value"? Or maybe "vector"?

Comment: From what I have googled (why didn't you ?), it seems to be the environment variables and seems to not be portable so you should not use it anyway.

Comment: without context an abbreviation can mean anything, [ENVP](https://soundcloud.com/envp-donna-johnson)

Comment: If it's "ENvironment Variables", where did the 'p' go?

Comment: @nngm p stands for pointer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++ `argc` argument count, `envp` environment variables pointer

Comment: The name "argv" came from B, where it was a global variable, a "vector" according to the manual. `argv[0]` was the index of the last valid argument, so there was no `argc`.

Comment: No idea why this question is closed on the basis of "needs details or clarity". It's clear as day. This is a great question. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The meaning is:

- `argv` stands for ***arg**ument **v**ector*
- `argc` for ***arg**ument **c**ount*, and
- `envp` for ***env**ironment **p**ointer*.

We can discuss about the good or bad naming convention, but it's a historic usage that dates back to the beginning of the C language: [B.W.Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) and [D.Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) used already `argc` and `argv` for `main()` in their first edition of [*The C Programming language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) in 1978.

The `envp` [was added](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) later from the UNIX development and is an alternative for using the [`environ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) pointer.  I found a reference to it in a book from 1986, but it's certainly even older.  It doesn't need a count, because it's null terminated.  Note that it is [not portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10321435/3723423) and therefore the use of [`getenv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) should be preferred.

Comment: names are just historical textbook names, any identifiers could be used instead.

Comment: @Serge Indeed. It's just a convention.  OP wanted just to know why it was called like that.

Comment: In Kernighan and Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, “argv” is shown in the index as “argument vector”, not “argument value”. Suggested formatting: **arg**ument **v**ector, **arg**ument **c**ount, **env**ironment **p**ointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Excellent idea ! Thanks ! Done ✅

Comment: argv[argc] is also NULL (so argv is also null-terminated). Hence argc is also redundant. Isn't it?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB interesting. Can you clarify your source that states this equality?

Comment: @Christophe [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160#standard-command-line-arguments).

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB This is a very valid and interesting remark.  Having checked further, it appears that argv[argc]==NULL is guaranteed by POSIX and by the C standard since the first C89.  However, in the original K&R nothing as such was ever mentioned, and all their examples (that have been copied by hundreds of thousands of programmers afterwards) use loops on argc without ever going out of bounds.  This is how inertia is created: since everybody was using argc,  even if it's redundant, it had to be kept for backwards compatibility. (I learned C with K&R and never went beyond argc-1 ;-) )

Comment: Note that `argv` is also null terminated, despite the count.

Answer (score 5):

In Kernighan and Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 1978, `argv` is shown in the index, on page 221, as:

> `argv` argument vector 110

The text on pages 110-114 contains no further indication of the derivation of `argc` or `argv`, other than their semantics. `envp` does not appear in the index.

In the second edition, 1988, the text in the corresponding section, on page 114, says:

> … two arguments. The first (conventionally called `argc`, for argument count) is the number of command-line arguments the program was invoked with; the second (`argv`, for argument vector) is…

Again in the second edition, `envp` does not appear in the index.

The Unix specification, IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016, *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*, says in the section on `environ`, `execl`, and related routines:

> Some implementations provide a third argument to main() called envp. This is defined as a pointer to the environment.

This is consistent with `envp` standing for **env**ironment **p**ointer.

Comment: Interesting! I have only the first version, where *vector* only appears in the index.  FYI,  the use of envp is much older, since I already found a mention of it as ***pointer to** an array of character pointers that are **the environment** of the executed program* in Maurice Bach's 1986 book *The design of the UNIX® operating system*

Answer (score 1):

From C language spec:

> **J.5.1 Environment arguments**
>   1 In a hosted environment, the `main` function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`,
>   that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to char, each of which points to a string
>   that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program
>   (5.1.2.2.1).

Note that this third argument is not listed in C++ language spec, though some implementations are still fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied the etymology of conventional argument names, so please excuse my speculative answer.

'env' rather obviously means environment or environment variables.

The 'p' in envp could be initialism for parameter(s) or, perhaps pointer(s) referring to the type. Perhaps even environment variables of the **P**rogram.

Etymology isn't really important for the meaning of the program, so I recommend not to worry about it too much.

Comment: Just an intellectual curiosity :)