# execve not giving outputting with "which" command

Tags: c++, c, bash, execve

I've been working on understanding the execve command, and I've encountered an issue that I've narrowed down. I'm puzzled as to why execve doesn't work with the "which" command but works perfectly fine with other commands like "ls". I obtained the paths for these executables directly from the Bash shell.

Here's the code that doesn't work with "which":

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *cmd_args_joined[] = {"which", "ls", NULL};
    char    cmd_plus_path[] = "/usr/bin/which";

    if (execve(cmd_plus_path, cmd_args_joined, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("failed at execve\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

And here's the code that works with "ls":

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *cmd_args_joined[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char    cmd_plus_path[] = "/bin/ls";

    if (execve(cmd_plus_path, cmd_args_joined, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("failed at execve\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me understand and resolve this issue. Thank you!

I initially suspected that I might have inadvertently redirected the standard output to another file. However, given that the code above doesn't employ dup2() for redirection, I must conclude that my initial assumption was incorrect.

Comment: With NULL as the environment string pointer, you prevent "which" from accessing "PATH=..." Consider using `execv()` instead... (And, "doesn't work" does not provide a lot of information about your problem.)

Comment: Note that there is no need to test (or save) the return value from any of the `exec*()` family of functions.  If the call succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Fun fact: a successful call to `execvp` corrupts `errno`. Guess how I discovered it.

Comment: @Joshua: can you explain what that means?  Were you using `vfork()` instead of `fork()`?  Or `clone()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yup. `vfork()` was used.

Comment: @Jacob: Well, if you use ‘`vfork()`, you don’t get full separation of the processes until after the child execs or exits.  I don’t use `vfork()` because the constraints on it (and its behaviour generally)  are too whimsical for my comfort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `posix_spawn()` calls `vfork()` internally now. I didn't check if it has internal fixups for the errno stomping or not.

Comment: Funnily enough, `vfork()` is not specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't your call to execve. The problem is with no environment, `which` won't find `ls` and produce no output. Had you checked the return code you would find it to be nonzero.

Stupid fix:

```
if (execve(cmd_plus_path, cmd_args_joined, environ) < 0)
```

The exported variable `environ` is the process environment. You can also capture it as the third argument to main, but that's deprecated.

Comment: Where is the third argument to `main()` deprecated?  One curiosity: `environ` is just about the only POSIX global variable without a header that declares it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10321474/14768

Comment: The rationale in the POSIX specification for [`execvp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) says: _Some implementations provide a third argument to `main()` called `envp`. This is defined as a pointer to the environment. The ISO C standard specifies invoking `main()` with two arguments, so implementations must support applications written this way. […] Implementations are required to support the two-argument calling sequence, but this does not prohibit an implementation from supporting `envp` as an optional third argument._ That is **not** deprecated.