# Global variable needs to be passed as a parameter

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, operating-system

I have a function that is copying the contents of the `envp` array that contains the global variables. The function is successful in copying the contents, however, when it returns, it seems like the array pointer is pointing somewhere else altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// allow up to 64 environment variables
#define MAXENV 64

// local envp copy
char *envp_copy[MAXENV];

// current size of envp_copy
int envp_size = 0;

void copy_envp(char *envp[])
{
    for (long i = 0; i <= MAXENV; i++)
    {
        if (envp[i] == NULL)
        {
            envp_copy[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        envp_copy[i] = strdup(envp[i]);
        envp_size++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < envp_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[], char *envp_copy[])
{
    copy_envp(envp);
    for (int i = 0; i < envp_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
    }
}
```

I know that if I change the `copy_envp` function to take the array as variable

```
void copy_envp(char *envp[], char *envp_copy[]);
```

Then everything works as expected. But I am struggling to understand why the array has to be passed in as a parameter, even though it was declared globally.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[], char *envp_copy[])` Why does main take `envp_copy` as argument?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[], char *envp_copy[])` this is definitely invalid

Comment: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` are the only valid signatures.   Why does your definition of main take two extra arguments?  Did you just make up that signature?

Comment: If you remove `envp_copy` from the parameters to `main`, where it shouldn't be anyway, you'll also fix the issue that it shadows the global variable making it unavailable.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I literally have been at this for hours and that was the problem?! What are fresh set of eyes won't do. That fixed it.

Comment: @JohnGordon `envp` is a common addition on Unix systems, although not specified by POSIX. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable

Comment: @John ```int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])``` is also valid

Comment: From K&R: "_(argv, for argument vector)_" ... Better to use `char *envv[]` to keep to the naming convention established by the language authors...

Comment: You cannot define the interface to `main()` as you like.... it is one of several, by definition, and you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard defines `main()` as taken either 0 or 2 arguments, or an "implementation-defined" manner and I only know of a 3rd argument with the `char *environment[]` and not a of a 4th argument which in your program shadows the global variable.

Here is an implementation that avoids the global variable and addresses the memory leak (of the strings being `strdup()`).  It also addresses the out of bound access; `i = 0; i <= MAXENV` is MAXENV + 1 loop iterations.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXENV 64

char **copy_envp(const char *env[]) {
    char **copy = malloc(sizeof *copy * (MAXENV+1));
    if(!copy) return NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < MAXENV && env[i]; i++)
        copy[i] = strdup(env[i]);
    copy[i] = NULL;
    // optionally shrink the copy to size
    char **tmp = realloc(copy, sizeof *copy * (i+1));
    return tmp ? tmp : copy;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    char **envp_copy = copy_envp((const char **) envp);
    if(!envp_copy) {
        printf("copy_envp empty or failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; envp_copy[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
        free(envp_copy[i]);
    }
    free(envp_copy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Main signature is wrong.
Should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- the prototype for `main` is incorrect: your system might support `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])` but not with the extra `envp_copy` argument.  `envp_copy` is a global variable, it is available to all functions.  The code has undefined behavior because the `main` prototype is incorrect. Furthermore, this extra argument definition hides the global variable so the loop in `main` does not access the global array, but one that does not exist, causing further undefined behavior.
- the `envp` array does not contain the global variables, it contains the definitions of the *environment* variables.
- int `copy_envp`, the loop should stop one step earlier: `for (size_t i = 0; i < MAXENV; i++)`. as coded you have undefined behavior if there are more than 64 environment variables because `envp_copy[MAXENV]` will be accessed beyond the end of the array.  For consistency, it should even stop at `MAXENV-1` to leave space for a `NULL` pointer at the end of the array.
- `envp_size` is incremented in `copy_envp` but not initialized to `0`, hence it will keep growing beyond the last copied item if the function is called more than once. Either initialize `i = envp_size` and `copy_envp` will append to the array or initialize `envp_size = 0` for consistency.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// allow up to 64 environment variables
#define MAXENV 64

// local envp copy
char *envp_copy[MAXENV];

// current size of envp_copy
int envp_size = 0;

void copy_envp(char *envp[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXENV - 1 && envp[i]; i++) {
        envp_copy[i] = strdup(envp[i]);
    }
    envp_copy[i] = NULL;
    envp_size = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < envp_size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    copy_envp(envp);
    for (int i = 0; i < envp_size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", envp_copy[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```