# Cleaning up an argv program

Tags: c, printing, output, argv

I have an argv c program, and it reverses the word, and sees if it's a palindrome. I just want to clean up the output and have it print the original input instead of the reversed one, but since it's argv, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *string = (char*)malloc(1000);                                                              
    string[0] = '\0';                                                                                

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)                                                                        
    strcat(string, argv[i]);

    for(j = 0; string[ j ]; j++)
    string[j] = tolower(string[ j ]);

    reverse(string);
    printf("Reverse of entered word is \"%s\".\n", string);

    result = is_palindrome(string);

    if ( result == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" is a palindrome.\n", string);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" is not a palindrome.\n", string); 

    system("pause");
}
```

I left out the rest of the functions, but you can see in the main the printf showing whether it is or isn't a palindrome. Not sure how to get that to equal the original input, and knowing the amount of arguments. Currently it prints the reversed string, when I think it would look better printing the original. I think I'm making this too hard but i'm not sure.

Comment: What is an `argv` program? All `main` may receive parameters through `argv`.

Comment: Why don't you just print the string *before* you reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is reversing the reversed string, another way is passing a single argument/string to the program using double quotes:

```
./program "a man a plan a canal panama"
```

instead of

```
./program a man a plan a canal panama
```

Then you don't need to loop through the args.

Comment: I'll try to reverse the reversed already, but this is for a class, and the professor will be inputting the strings, so I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** since OP says the professor will enter the sentence (without quotes!).

This can be done simply using MSVC library functions. Because `strdup` allocated memory, that clean up is also needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fatal(char *msg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, argslen = 0;
    char *inp, *rev;
    if (argc < 2)                           // check num args
        fatal("Need a string argument");
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++)                  // figure input length
        argslen += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;     // include spaces and EOS
    inp = malloc(argslen);                  // memory for concatenation
    if (inp == NULL)
        fatal("Memory allocation error");
    strcpy(inp, argv[1]);                   // prime with first arg
    for (i=2; i<argc; i++) {                // concat other args
        strcat(inp, " ");
        strcat(inp, argv[i]);
    }

    rev = strdup(inp);                      // make a copy
    if (rev == NULL)
        fatal("Memory allocation error");
    strrev(rev);                            // reverse the copy
    printf("Testing: \"%s\"\n", inp);
    if (stricmp(inp, rev) == 0)             // case insensitive test
        printf("Is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("Not a palindrome\n");
    free (inp);                             // release mine
    free (rev);                             // release library's
    return 0;
}

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}
```

Program result:

```
>test Able was I ere I saw Elba
Testing: "Able was I ere I saw Elba"
Is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions:
The amount of arguments is in `argc` - see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898021/mainint-argc-char-argv) for more details on `argc` and `argv[]`.

On how to print the original string, you can either print the string before you call `reverse()`, store the original string in a temporary variable to output later or reverse again before you print it. The third option would look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *string = (char*)malloc(1000);                                                              
    string[0] = '\0';                                                                                

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)                                                                        
    strcat(string, argv[i]);

    for(j = 0; string[ j ]; j++)
    string[j] = tolower(string[ j ]);

    reverse(string);
    printf("Reverse of entered word is \"%s\".\n", string);

    result = is_palindrome(string);

    if ( result == 1)
        printf("\"%s\" is a palindrome.\n", reverse(string));
    else
        printf("\"%s\" is not a palindrome.\n", reverse(string)); 

    system("pause");
}
```