# what does asterisk( printf ("%s\n",*argv) ) means?

Tags: c

what does asterisk(*++argv) mean?

```
void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 while (--argc)              
  {
    printf ("%s\n", *++argv);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's just the normal dereference operation. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access

Comment: it is about the pointer? OK, i got it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding 'main(int argc, char \*argv\[\])'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898021/regarding-mainint-argc-char-argv)

Comment: I just dont have any knowledge about the pointer, but i know pointer.
I didn't find that it was pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `argv` is a pointer to a pointer of `char` type

`*argv` points to the first argument string in the argv array, which is same as `argv[0]`, similarly `*(argv + 1)` and `argv[1]` point to second argument string and so on..

[Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2094666/8701568)

Comment: `argv` is `char*[]`, not just `char*` .   Perhaps you could explain how the code iteratees through its arguments, and post a runtime example.  That would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` stands for argument vector and it holds argc + 1(int - argument count and the last one is `NULL` by default.) number of elements. Like in the char arrays, first element of the argument vector holds the address for the whole argument vector. So, by passing argument vector pointer (`*argv[]`), program gets the char typed parameters when main function is called.

To see how to get argument vector parameters and use them please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898043/5198054).

Comment: " it holds argc number of elements" --> `argv[]` has `argc+1` elements defined.  The last is `NULL`.