# How to provide parameters with command Line

Tags: c, command-line, parameters

i'm trying to deliver parameters for a program with the command line. 
I want, that the program is working as shown now:
- start the program with parameter "program.exe " 
- then the  should be useable in the programm
How can i approach this thing?

Here is the essential part of my programm:

```
int main(){
int length;
unsigned int i=0;
length=strlen(word);
for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
       printf("%d",word[i]);
       }
}
```

And i wanted to add this word[] parameter via command line. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look on it : [what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: Or for plain C look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3734111/694576

Answer (score 1):

For command line arguments Use argv and argc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
int i;
printf("argc is %d\n",argc);
for(i = 1; i < argc ; i++){
        printf("%d \n", atoi(argv[i]));
}

}
```

Run your program as

```
./a.out 10 20 30
argc is 4
10 
20 
30
```

Comment: Thanks, is this function also useable for only one argument?

Comment: Thanks in stackoverflow is Upvote or Accepting Answer !! yes it will be usable for one argument also

Comment: What should be the expected output, please?

Comment: Also `i` is undefined.

Comment: The output should make the word to an number .. ascii codes .. the "a" should be converted into a "97" ..

Comment: "*The output should make the word to an number*" the code definitely does *not do this*. The code you show takes the pointer to each of the arguments passed on the command-line and subtracts `'0'` and prints it. Better test your code before posting it to the world.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    return 0;
}
```

1. argc => argument count / command line parameter count
2. argv[x] => argument value / parameter text at position