# Are the strings in argv modifiable?

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments, argv

I just wrote a small program that reads command line arguments in C, nothing too difficult. I was also modifying them, for example changing the first character of the parameter to uppercase.

I know that you shouldn't modify string literals as it can cause undefined behavior, so was just wondering if the strings in the `*argv[]` are literals that you shouldn't change.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the arguments to main() for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734111/what-are-the-arguments-to-main-for)

Comment: It is not a literal. You can change it.

Comment: I know what they are for and what they mean, just wondering if they were literals.

Comment: @user007 Not a duplicate. That question doesn't mention anything about string literals.

Comment: If you didn't write a string in your program, and wrap it in quotes, it's not a string literal.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart oh wow I did not know that, thanks!

Comment: Compiled code does not have string literals. As much as _integer constants_, keywords and operators, they are syntax elements in the source code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the C11 standard draft N1570, §5.1.2.2.1/2:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv`
>   array shall be modiﬁable by the program, and retain their last-stored
>   values between program startup and program termination.

**They are modifiable.** That means they are not string literals.

But **be careful**: the upper citation only refers to pointers **to strings**, excluding the obligatory null pointer at `argv[argc]`<sup>1</sup>.
From the C11 standard draft N1570, §5.1.2.2.1/2 (same as above)<sup>1</sup>:

> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer

---

Notes:

- Something regarding this sentence:

  > I know that you shouldn't modify string literals as it can cause
  >   undefined behavior [...]

  "can"? It does always. Undefined behavior includes expected, as if well-defined, and unexpected behavior.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @black!</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know it always causes undefined behavior I guess I should make my question more explicit, I'll change it now.

Comment: That this imply that the pointers themselves can be modified or not? I.e. can one do: `argv[0] = NULL `

Comment: @2501 Good question. IMO, "The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modiﬁable by the program [...]" only refers to `argc` and `argv` themselves and the strings. I'll dig somewhat and report back.

Comment: @cad: there is not anything on where these strings should be stored, right? As far as the local program goes, its arguments may come from a hardcoded string in a ROM. Also, making them *longer* should be out of the question. So you can safely change the *pointers* (because local) but not the strings themselves (because external).

Comment: @Jongware As far as I can tell, the first quotation directly contradicts that: "[...] the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modiﬁable by the program [...]," so, except if the arguments are **copied** from ROM, they cannot be stored in read-only memory. Or does "the strings" refer to the pointers themselves? IMO, it does not.

Comment: @2501 I didn't find anything sensible, so I'll just pretend, accordingly to § 4/1 (same standard as in my answer): "Undeﬁned behavior is otherwise indicated [...] by the omission of any explicit deﬁnition of behavior." Doesn't mean I'm right, tho.

Comment: @cad I just noticed it says right there: *The parameters argc and argv* and the strings pointed to by the argv array *shall
be modifiable* by the program. => The parameters shall be modifiable.

Comment: @2501 Of course I can. :P  But it only talks about the arguments themselves and the strings, not about the pointers to the strings.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? I think it is. By pointers I means the values in the parameter argv at certain indexes, and I gave the example argv[0]. So it is defined to do argv[0] = NULL.

Comment: @2501 IMO, a string is the actual string of characters (a character being `argv[0][0]` for example), not the pointer to them. But anyway, if "string" refers to the pointers, what about the actual characters?

Comment: @cad A string is defined as a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by a null character. I think you can modify everything, otherwise the text would be more specific, but I'm not 100% sure about the pointers themselves.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `argv[argc] == NULL`-thing is a guarantee from the environment, not a prohibition on modification by the program.

Comment: @2501 I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105918/are-the-pointers-to-strings-in-argv-modifiable) regarding that, just so that you know.

Answer (score 3):

The arrays that support the strings in `argv` are modifiable.
But you have no way to know their sizes.

I would frown upon seeing code that (tries to) increase the size of the strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// this program may behave erraticaly
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
        printf("original argv[%d] is %s\n", k, argv[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
        strcat(argv[k], " foo"); // add foo to each argv string
        printf("first modification to argv[%d] is %s\n", k, argv[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int k = argc; k > 1; k--) {
        strcat(argv[k - 1], " bar"); // add bar to each argv string
        printf("final argv[%d] is %s\n", k - 1, argv[k - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, calling that program with `one two three` arguments produces

```
original argv[1] is one
original argv[2] is two
original argv[3] is three

first modification to argv[1] is one foo
first modification to argv[2] is foo foo
first modification to argv[3] is foo foo

final argv[3] is foo foo bar
final argv[2] is foo foo foo bar bar
final argv[1] is one foo foo foo bar bar bar
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah I wasn't really increasing or decreasing the size just changing a character to be upper or lower case.