# Checking for command line arguments in C

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, argv, argc

I wrote this code to take input from the command line, and depending on the input, will perform a set of actions, or if the input is incorrect, throws an error. However, I also need to check if no arguments are supplied, which I try to account for in my else statement.

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-L") == 0) 
{
    //does stuff
}


else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-W") == 0)
{

    //does stuff

}

else if (*(argv[1]) != 1)
{
    puts("error: invalid input");
}

else //should check if no arguments
{
    puts("error: expected command line argument");
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault whenever there are no arguments from the command line, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I have also tried to write the else statement this way:

```
else if(argc < 2)
{
    puts("error: expected command line argument");
    return 1;
}
```

This was based on my previous research on here where I found "C produce error if no argument is given in command line," but it won't work either. I am a beginner in C and do not fully understand argc and argv, so if anyone has any suggestions or logic I'm completely overlooking, please let me know.

Comment: Consider learning about the [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) function, a standard library call that makes it easy to handle command line options in a standard fashion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the arguments to main() for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734111/what-are-the-arguments-to-main-for)

Comment: Clearly you should be checking to see how many arguments you receive **before** you start using those arguments and not **after**, right?

Comment: @KenWhite That would make sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `if argc < 2` before anything else.

Else you get segmentation fault because `argv[index]` could be something you have not privileges to access.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, make sure you never try to access an index of argv that is greater or equal to argc. In your case, you are accessing index 1 when the last available index is 0 (argc is 1), that's why the segmentation fault. See this post for more info: [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: argc can never be zero as the first argument is always the filename

Comment: @Fredrik That's right, I edited my answer. Thanks for catching that.